# PyGtk: How to sort Items In liststore associated to CellRendererCombo

Tags: gtk, pygtk

How can I sort the Items in ListStore attached to a CellRendererCombo

```
cellrenderer_combo = gtk.CellRendererCombo()
...
liststore = gtk.ListStore(str)
    item_list = ["Item1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4", "Item5", "Item6"]
    for item in item_list:
        liststore.append([item])

self.cellrenderer_combo.set_property("model", self.liststore)
```

How can I sort the "Items" in Liststore in Descending order ???

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the items are not going to change, then just sort them before you add them to the list store:

```
item_list = ['These', 'items', 'are', 'not', 'going', 'to', 'change']
item_list.sort(reverse=True)
```

If the items are going to change and you want to keep them sorted in the combo box, then use a [gtk.TreeModelSort](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreemodelsort.html):

```
sorted = gtk.TreeModelSort(liststore)
self.cellrenderer_combo.props.model = self.liststore
```

Comment: The items in the combobox is dynamic. So gtk.TreeModelSort will do. But how to sort it in 'descending' order?

Comment: [gtk.TreeSortable.set_sort_column_id()](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtktreesortable.html#method-gtktreesortable--set-sort-column-id) allows you to choose ascending or descending sort.